# Python3: Sort a 3-levels nested dictionary by value

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, lambda

I've been trying to sort a dictionary of dictionaries of dictionaries (3-levels) but had no luck. I need to sort it by the "common_RMSD" field value. This is an input example (sorry I don't know how to format properly the dictionary here...)

```
my_dict = {'E': {
         'E': {
            'common_sup': <Bio.PDB.Superimposer.Superimposer object at 0x08451030>, 
            'common_sample_chain_ID': 'E', 
            'common_ref_chain_ID': 'E', 
            'common_RMSD': 2.013799285922141e-14}, 
          'F': {
            'common_sup': <Bio.PDB.Superimposer.Superimposer object at 0x08786FB0>, 
            'common_sample_chain_ID': 'F', 
            'common_ref_chain_ID': 'E', 
            'common_RMSD': 0.1207801497077146}}, 
         'F': {
          'E': {
            'common_sup': <Bio.PDB.Superimposer.Superimposer object at 0x08AB6410>, 
            'common_sample_chain_ID': 'E', 
            'common_ref_chain_ID': 'F', 
            'common_RMSD': 0.12078014970771417}, 
          'F': {
            'common_sup': <Bio.PDB.Superimposer.Superimposer object at 0x08AB63F0>, 
            'common_sample_chain_ID': 'F', 
            'common_ref_chain_ID': 'F', 
            'common_RMSD': 7.559143985024071e-15}
         }  }
```

I have read in previous posts the use of lamdda and items() functions. With items() I can get through the first value of the first key-value level (which is the second dictionary), but I don't know how to go further inside the dictionary.

```
sorted(dict.items(), key = lambda x: x[1]... )
```

Is there a possibility to reorder the whole dictionary, sorting the nested dictionaries by the 'common_RMSD' value? So that when I loop through them, the first dictionary has the lowest 'common_RMSD' value? If not, then output a tuple with ('common_sup','common_sample_chain_ID','common_ref_chain_ID','common_RMSD'), again ordered by 'common_RMSD'

Comment: What do you expect to be the result for your example data??

Comment: Dictionarys have no order (`*`) - why sort them? (`*`) they got insort order from 3.7 on ...  but that will not resort itself without recreating the whole dicts... so what is the _purpose_ of sorting them?

Comment: `dict` shadows the class name

Comment: I need to loop through the dictionary, being the first nested dictionary the one with the lowest 'common_RMSD' value.